# Проблема с headers. Python 3 и requests

Tags: python, requests

Api работает на oauth и нужно предоставить ему ключ в формате json, в строке headers. При отправке верного ключа и запроса, API возвращает 401.

Ради интереса попробовал сделать этот же запрос в программе insomnia. Там api сервиса возвратил нужный json и всё работает.
Вопрос - почему это не работает с модулем requests?

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "headers": json.dumps({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "<key>"
    })
}

test = requests.get("https://osu.ppy.sh/api/v2/users/<user_id>/scores/best", headers=headers)

print(test.text)
```

[image: Демонстрация отправки запроса через программу]

Comment: json.dumps уберите, непонятно зачем он тут вообще нужен

Comment: А ещё непонятно зачем у вас headers вложен внутрь headers

Comment: @andreymal, без json.dumps модуль requests определяет переменную как словарь и вываливается в исключение. headers внутри headers для удобства, над названием можно подумать.

Comment: Нет, исключение вываливается из-за того, что вы вложили headers внутрь headers. Это не вопрос удобства, вы просто сделали неправильно

Comment: `headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "<key>"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "<key>"
}
    
requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

Непонятно зачем вы делаете json dumps.
Просто передайте headers как словарь

При авторизации через OAuth обычно указывается следующий хедер. Подробнее изучайте документацию к вашему API.

```
token = "ваш токен"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    ....
}
```